# Gradle Kotlin DSL: how to configure subprojects using typesafe api

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Gradle 6.1.1

I have been trying to convert my projects' Gradle files using Kotlin DSL in a **type-safe** manner but so far failed. All my projects are multi-project builds in Java. The idea is to factorize/deduplicate the common configurations of the submodules (whether in the 'subprojects' block of the root module or in a separate 'kts' file I don't care).
The official documentation states that it is not possible to have type-safe with 'subprojects' and apply(from = 'shared.gradle.kts') (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html).

It works as below but it is rather anoying:

```
plugins {
    idea
    eclipse
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")

    dependencies {
       "implementation"("com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre")
       //...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to factorise the module configurations for all the submodules in a type-safe manner ?  If not... does gradle plan to allow it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle `6.1.1`  [Type-safe model accessors](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors) reads:

> Only the main project build scripts and precompiled project script plugins have type-safe model accessors. Initialization scripts, settings scripts, script plugins do not. *These limitations will be removed in a future Gradle release*.

Whatever "future release" might mean ...while [Cross-configuring projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_cross_project_configuration) reads:

> Cross project configuration is a mechanism by which you can configure a project from another project’s build script. A common example is when you configure subprojects in the root project build script. *Taking this approach means that you won’t be able to use type-safe accessors for model elements contributed by the plugins*. You will instead have to rely on string literals and the standard Gradle APIs.

Comment: In a future release... I hope it won't be in forever :'(.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```
plugins {
    java // just simply add java plugin to the root plugins section
    idea
    eclipse
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")

    dependencies {
       implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre")
    }
}
```

In this case `java` plugin will be applied to the root project that turns to creation of `build` folder in the root. To avoid `build` folder creation you need to disable `build` and `jar` tasks for the root project:

```
tasks {
    jar {
        isEnabled = false
    }
    build {
        isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

See also [gradle: disable creation of the build folder at root in multi-projects application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518039/gradle-disable-creation-of-the-build-folder-at-root-in-multi-projects-applicati)

Comment: this only work for plugins you can safely apply to the root project as well, but still a good idea, +1